# Slow query performance on simple select

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have 2 tables:

1. Organization (2.500.000 rows)
2. City (35.000 rows)

'Organization' has 'city_id' set as foreign key to 'cities'.'id':

Organization:

```
ALTER TABLE public.organization
  ADD CONSTRAINT organization_pkey1 PRIMARY KEY(id);

ALTER TABLE public.organization
  ADD CONSTRAINT organization_city_id_381976b6f7d84e86_fk_city_id FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
      REFERENCES public.city (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

CREATE INDEX organization_c7141997
  ON public.organization
  USING btree
  (city_id);
```

City:

```
ALTER TABLE public.city
  ADD CONSTRAINT city_pkey1 PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

Query below takes 6.2 seconds to finish:

```
SELECT 
    org.id
FROM organization AS org
INNER JOIN city ON city.id = org.city_id 
WHERE org.id>=1 AND org.id<=3736809
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 100000;
```

Explain analyze result:

```
Limit  (cost=22129.97..22340.23 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=6268.343..6274.803 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1104.52..521879.44 rows=2476878 width=4) (actual time=29.056..6259.761 rows=101000 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (org.city_id = city.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on organization org  (cost=0.00..465045.17 rows=2476878 width=8) (actual time=0.014..6026.781 rows=101000 loops=1)
              Filter: ((id >= 1) AND (id <= 3736809))
        ->  Hash  (cost=694.23..694.23 rows=32823 width=4) (actual time=29.014..29.014 rows=32823 loops=1)
              Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1154kB
              ->  Seq Scan on city  (cost=0.00..694.23 rows=32823 width=4) (actual time=0.008..13.538 rows=32823 loops=1)
Total runtime: 6275.272 ms
```

**Is this an expected query performance ?**

**How to speed query execution ?**

p.s. - i include some of my settings below

```
PG 9.3 on MacOS 10.9.5 (8GB ram)

Postgresql.conf:
default_statistics_target = 50
maintenance_work_mem = 448MB
constraint_exclusion = on
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = 5632MB
work_mem = 44MB 
wal_buffers = 8MB 
checkpoint_segments = 16 
shared_buffers = 1792MB
max_connections = 80
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What's the point of doing offset without ordering?

Comment: Mladen, i am indexing database for use with Sphinx search.

Comment: Did you try PostgreSQL full text search instead of Sphinx?  I didn't ask about indexing, I asked about getting data doing limit and offset. Check my answer for more efficient data retrieval.

Comment: Yes i did :) Sphinx is way faster at some operations. I am still checking your answer below.

Comment: Using materialized view will definitely speed up your query. :D I hope that you are aware of costs using Materialized views.

Comment: See the costs of your query: http://explain.depesz.com/s/2yxw . It takes 6 sec to scan your organization table. Do you know the size of your tables? \d+ in psql console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of results that's why your index is not used. Make your query more restrictive.

It seems that you are using pagination:
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page